# Bidirectional messaging with request-response pattern (Protobuf for data serialization)

Tags: sockets, rabbitmq, protocol-buffers, zeromq, amqp

The base problem is as follows:

- Two nodes communicating over a **single** socket;
- Request-reply pattern;
- Both nodes are client and server, i.e. node A makes requests to node B and node B makes requests to node A;

This would be easily solved with two sockets but I have only one. You can think of the problem as having to create multiple *virtual sockets/channels* over a single socket. **Do you know of a well-tested messaging library that would support such use case?**

---

In addition:

- Support for C++ and Java;
- The data serialization is handled by me using Google Protocol Buffers; and
- If it is possible to achieve all this using RPC then great, otherwise I'll manage using protobuf.

I'd prefer not to have to write my own library and use something which is well-tested and well-support. I've looked into ZeroMQ but it doesn't seem to support the third requirement (request-reply pattern from A to B and from B to A simultaneously over a single socket). RabbitMQ is another possibility but may not support this requirement either. (I don't have experience with these libraries so maybe I'm wrong...)

(I wonder if I'm asking for too much.)

Comment: I know this question is almost a year's old, so I was wondering if you figured out an answer since then.

Comment: @GeorgeAntoniadis -- Not, no solution. The requirements I was given changed so I used two sockets, one for each direction.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a complete answer for you, but I note that what you're asking for is emphatically supported by [Cap'n Proto](https://capnproto.org)'s RPC protocol: calls can be initiated in either direction.

It's not exactly what you want because:

- Cap'n Proto has its own serialization format. The usage model is heavily inspired by Protobufs, but it isn't protobufs.
- The Java implementation does not yet support RPC (planned, though).
- If you care about Windows: the C++ implementation does not yet support RPC on MSVC, mostly due to MSVC being woefully behind on C++11 support. :/

But it might be worth checking out, for inspiration if nothing else.

(Disclosure: I'm the author of Cap'n Proto, and also the author of most of Google's open source Protobuf code.)

Comment: Do you have a particular link that talks about bidirectional communication?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai In Cap'n Proto? The idea is that you can make a call where you pass a new object reference as a parameter, where that object reference points back to an object implemented by the caller (client). Then, the callee (server) can start making calls back to that object, thus you have bidirectional communication. I don't think the docs present this specifically as "bidirectional communication", but there is lots of information about sending object references as this is a core feature of Cap'n Proto. https://capnproto.org/rpc.html

Comment: So you worked on protocol buffers! Have you heard of the new Google's gRPC? I read it has "bidirectional streaming".

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Yes. gRPC is based largely on Google's internal RPC system which I worked closely with for years. I actually implemented the first version of "bidirectional streaming" used in Google, though it was later rewritten to integrate more closely with the low-level protocol. In any case, IMHO, Cap'n Proto's approach is far superior. :)